# .NET Application monitoring tools

Tags: windows, .net, monitoring, profiling

We have been looking for an application performance monitoring tool for some time and did not get quite a success in it. Our product environment consists of around 25 windows servers and each running 4-5 applications (web service/windows service/.net processes).

Here are our performance monitoring tool's requirements:

1. It can monitor our various distributed applications like web services, windows services, .net processes.
2. It can capture the high-level monitoring information like CPU and memory usage etc.
3. If any issues come up, It can also allow you to dig deeper till the call stack level and view the process profiling data.
4. It should be deployed on-premise for security concerns.
5. The tool should be cost effective (around 10k-15k per year for our above environment)

Almost all of the existing APM tools can fulfill the 1st and 2nd requirement. Currently, the 3rd requirement can only be fulfilled by the SAS-based-tools which is in conflict with our 4th requirement.

After some research, we found dynatrace can fulfill requirements 1-4, but its on-premise version is quite expensive and conflicting with our requirement 5.

We are not able to find any APM tool that can satisfy all our five requirements above.

Please help us to find if such kind of tool exists in the market.

Answer (score 2):

@Puneet, with the scant details relating to your specific technology stack and architecture it is difficult to give you a precise answer.

But, on a high-level, I suggest you take a serious look at the set of open source monitoring tools used by StackExchange, which in my view would give you the kind of broad environment monitoring capabilities and decent "drill-down" capabilities at the same time.

Specifically, I would recommend Opserver, Miniprofiler, Bosun and StackExchange.Exceptional
https://github.com/opserver/Opserver

If there are any gaps, you can always supplement it by developing such capabilities on your own (and consider contributing it back to the open source community).

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions. I really appreciate it. From our side, we are planning to use AppDynamics. It fulfills almost all the requirements I have stated above except the 5th one. It's an expensive tool. But we are trying to prioritize the monitored applications so that we can reduce the cost.